# How to make a transparent black color in a rectangular box. (color is black, but it needs to be transparent and need to show the screen behind)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-palette

How to make a transparent black color in a rectangular box. (color is black, but it needs to be transparent and need to show the screen behind)

I have designed link below, but it is fully black. I have changed a clor code, but it is not in black transparent.

Image which I have added as a dropdown is black

[image]

If i add any other transparent color it shows as below. Rectangle area get thicked

[image]

How can I make the whole as transparent black as below. Also I need the whole black to change to the below color

[image]

My Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000"/>
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="35dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="1dp" android:bottom="10dp" android:bottomRightRadius="100dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-30"
            android:pivotX="100%"
            android:pivotY="0%"
            >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/black"  />
            </shape>
        </rotate>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side.

Answer (score 1):

Add alpha to the view. No need to edit the shape.

```
<View
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"/>
```

This works if you run the application. **What the design editor shows is different from what the application shows, so you need to test it!**

Answer (score -1):

```
android:background="#CC000000"
```

in XML

where CC is the alpha value, 00 is the red factor, 00 is the green factor, and 00 is the blue factor.

**Some opacity code:**

```
100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5%  — 0D
0% —  00
```

Comment: But the rectangle color makes a dark black color when applying this for both color. And it looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/92u8K.png

Comment: remove second shape solid color

Comment: If I remove this it does not show the arrow

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

***ic_chat_bubble_24.xml:***

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:alpha="0.28"// customize on your own
    android:autoMirrored="true"
    android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
        android:pathData="M20,2H4c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v18l4,-4h14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2V4c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2z" />
</vector>
```

and rotate it 180 degree

***ic_chat.xml***

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_chat_bubble_24"
    android:fromDegrees="180">

</rotate>
```

[image: output]

Comment: Can you let me know how can I increase the width and height of the chat_bubble when according to the list of items in the popup. I have the popup with multiple text

Comment: set `ic_chat.xml` as the background of your view(TextView,LinearLayout) so that this will behave according to the view's height and width